# I want the PHP header to redirect the whole page, not just the div

Tags: php, html, redirect

Greetings,

I'm using the following command..

```
header("location:login.php");
```

However, when it executes, it only affects the DIV it's currently in. How do I make it affect the whole page?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I think you have to give more context. Is your php page being called using AJAX? There are numerous possibilities as to why you have this issue.

Comment: It should redirect you from current page to login.php, so it should affect all page. Could you show your code, because theoretically you do everything well maybe its bug in your code?

Comment: @user121136: What everybody's trying to get at here is that the php `header` function *DOES* affect the whole page (well, the whole *HTTP request*, anyway). There must be something about the architecture of your page that's giving you the impression that the `div` is being redirected. Perhaps the `div` contains an `iframe` or is being filled by javascript? Please provide more info about the context to receive more useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

it should not unless it executes inside an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to affect the whole page, why didn't you just put it at the beginning of the file?

Alternatively, if you want to redirect a page, use can also use Javascript to handle that for you, i.e.

```
<div id="whatever"><script>window.location = 'login.php';</script></div>
```

Comment: technically, should be
`<div id="whatever"><script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='login.php';</script></div>`